# Can I attach a listener to the tabs in jQuery Tools?

Tags: jquery, jquery-tools

I'd like to run a bit of code when a user clicks on one of the tabs in a jQuery Tools tabs implementation.  Is this possible?  I'm dubious, based on an initial look at the source, but ideas are welcome.  I'm thinking about doing a slightly different version of the slide effect, one that makes my call in addition to the basic slide stuff.  Thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of course you can do it,

```
$(function() {
    // setup ul.tabs to work as tabs for each div directly under div.panes
    $(".tabs li a").click(function() {
       alert($(this).html() + " clicked");
        return false;
    });
    $("ul.tabs").tabs("div.panes > div");
});
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Jrhgz/)

Comment: Well, duh (blush)...  I was thinking in terms of building off the tabs code itself, but this obviously works.  Thanks for the brain reset.

Comment: I don't think you want a return false in there. Even on the demo, it will prevent the tab to appear selected.